# Saving Bitmap Image without shrinking width and height

Tags: android, image, bitmap

**What im trying to do** is to save an edited bitmap that is composed by 2 bitmaps overlayed. My application allows the user to draw on top of a picture and save it.

**My problem** is: when i save the result image, it gets smaller, even setting the quality to 100. So, if the user saves and edit the image multiple times, the image will get smaller and smaller.

I save the bitmap with this:

```
result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
```

I debugged the code, and at this point the width and height are fine, but after saving, the image shrinks.

I've researched for questions about this, but the ones i've found had no answers that could help me.

What i need is a way to save a bitmap without shrinking it, but i need it to be in image format, like JPG, PNG, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please log the size of `result` right before calling compress on it, is it what you would expect it to be? and what about the output file, what is its size?

Comment: The original size of the image is 520x390.  If i dont reload the image, its fine, it keeps the size, but when i reload it, the image size changes to 260x195. If i edit and reload again, it changes to 130x98. (Half size each time)

Comment: you will need to post your "reload" code

Comment: Sorry, i didnt want to mean the problem is the reload. When i save the bitmap with result.compress, before reloading, if i go to files and open the image, its already half sized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess is not at the time when you are saving the image, the issue is when you are editing the image (creating layers). Check that mechanism, maybe you are setting the image size there.

Comment: You're right, the compress method doesnt shrink the image, what i was doing wrong is that i was getting the size of the layout to save the bitmap in the overrided method onSizeChanged. Thank you.